# 11.04, 11.10, 12.04 won't boot under AMD FX-6100 with nVidia GeForce card

Tags: upgrade

Last night I tried to upgrade from Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04. The upgrade process had numerous errors, but I let it continue assuming that it would safer than interrupting it. Near the end, two conflicting messages appeared: "too many errors" and there was also a message telling me that the system was upgraded nonetheless. The only option I was presented at that point was to reboot, which I did, but the reboot just hanged. Then I tried to boot under "recovery mode" but the system gets into an infinite loop with the message. So I tried to re install from 10.10, which went OK, including updates. Then I upgraded to 11.04 (which I had done before) and the system fails to reboot after the update.

CPU: AMD FX-6100 Zambezi 3.3GHz Socket AM3+ 95W Six-Core 
MOBO: ASUS M5A97 AM3+ with Bios Version = 1208, which is the most updated as of 2012.05.25 
Video Card: EVGA 01G-P3-1556-KR GeForce GTX 550 Ti

Is there a compatibility problem caused by having an nVidia GeForce graphics card with an AMD CPU?

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem when I was upgrading. As far as I know, it has nothing to do with the graphics card. To fix this, you need to have a bootable Ubuntu Live USB or Live CD. Once you have booted into Ubuntu from the Live CD/USB, run the following command in the Terminal: `sudo apt-get install gparted`. After you have installed Gparted, open it up from the Dash, and select your hard drive from the top right-hand corner of Gparted.

[image]

Your screen should look something like the image above. You need to locate the partition that you have installed Ubuntu on. The filesystem of the partition should be **ext3**. In the image above, the partition Ubuntu is installed on would be **/dev/sda3**, because the filesystem is **ext3**. Now the you have found the partition that you have Ubuntu installed on, you need to run the commands below in the Terminal. Make sure to replace **/dev/sda1** with the Ubuntu partition you saw in Gparted.

`sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/myroot`

`sudo mount ‐‐bind /dev /mnt/myroot/dev`

`sudo mount ‐‐bind /proc /mnt/myroot/proc`

`sudo mount ‐‐bind /sys /mnt/myroot/sys`

`sudo chroot /mnt/myroot`

Now, run `apt-get install -f`. This should fix the errors encountered before, and complete the upgrade. Once `apt-get install -f` has finished running, you can reboot your computer and remove the Live CD/USB.